# react native, Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

When i login in my i.m getting memory leakage warning "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function"

Login function

```
 const onSubmit = () => {
    const checkValid = isValidData();
    if (checkValid) {
      updateState({isLoading: true});
      action
        .login_with_password({
          country_code: countryCode,
          phone_no: phoneNumber,
          password,
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          if (!res.data.ref_code_verified) {
            navigate(strings.nav_referalcode);
          } else if (!res.data.profile_completed) {
            navigate(strings.nav_profile_setUp);
          } else if (res.data.interest_ids.length == 0) {
            navigate(strings.nav_interest);
            updateState({isLoading: false});
          } else if (res.data.strongest_subject == null) {
            navigate(strings.nav_subject);
            updateState({isLoading: false});
          } else if (!res.data.competitive_exam) {
            navigate(strings.nav_exam);
            updateState({isLoading: false});
          } else if (res.data.purchased_plans.length == 0) {
            navigate(strings.nav_purchase_plan);
            updateState({isLoading: false});
          }

          updateState({isLoading: false});
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          showError(error.message);
          updateState({isLoading: false});
        });
    }
  };
```

and there is no useEffect in my home page. Why I'm getting that error? Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you *really* need to update state if you are navigating away from the page?

Comment: no, I don't need too, thanks :) now it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are likely seeing this warning because you are queueing a route transition to another page in your app ***and*** enqueueing a state update. The transition occurs, the component unmounts, and then React tries to update state but can't.

## Solution

Remove the state update calls from the app paths. Return the navigation, keep the last state update in the case that no conditions are met.

```
const onSubmit = () => {
  const checkValid = isValidData();
  if (checkValid) {
    updateState({ isLoading: true });
    action
      .login_with_password({
        country_code: countryCode,
        phone_no: phoneNumber,
        password,
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        if (!res.data.ref_code_verified) {
          return navigate(strings.nav_referalcode);
        } else if (!res.data.profile_completed) {
          return navigate(strings.nav_profile_setUp);
        } else if (!res.data.interest_ids.length) {
          return navigate(strings.nav_interest);
        } else if (res.data.strongest_subject === null) {
          return navigate(strings.nav_subject);
        } else if (!res.data.competitive_exam) {
          return navigate(strings.nav_exam);
        } else if (!res.data.purchased_plans.length) {
          return navigate(strings.nav_purchase_plan);
        }

        updateState({ isLoading: false });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        showError(error.message);
        updateState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: @DarkPrince Welcome. Cheers and good luck.